# How to get rid of Drive is not ready message box?

Tags: c#, winapi, ioexception

I have a malfunctioning USB stick that keeps connecting and disconnecting all the time with interval around 500ms, to save the files I have written a piece of software that copies files byte by byte, whenever USB stick disconnects, the software waits and then tries again and again.

It works, but from time to time Windows shows me a message box asking that it can't reach the drive and what it should do, I am wondering if I can somehow block this message from showing up so my application would keep working no matter what?

You can download the code from repository:
https://github.com/movsar/copynomatterwhat

And here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CopyNoMatterWhat
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static DriveInfo di;
        private static int DELAY = 250;

        private static void DirectoryCopy(string sourceDirName, string destDirName, bool copySubDirs)
        {
            // Get the subdirectories for the specified directory.
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirName);
            DirectoryInfo[] dirs;

            TryAgain:
            try {
                dirs = dir.GetDirectories();
                // If the destination directory doesn't exist, create it.
                if (!Directory.Exists(destDirName)) {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirName);
                }

                // Get the files in the directory and copy them to the new location.
                FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
                    string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, file.Name);
                    if (!(new FileInfo(temppath).Exists)) copy(file.FullName, temppath, file.Length);
                }

                // If copying subdirectories, copy them and their contents to new location.
                if (copySubDirs) {
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs) {
                        string temppath = Path.Combine(destDirName, subdir.Name);
                        DirectoryCopy(subdir.FullName, temppath, copySubDirs);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Thread.Sleep(DELAY);
                Debug.WriteLine("Get Files Fail");
                goto TryAgain;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Done");
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            di = new DriveInfo("f:");
            DirectoryCopy(@"F:\", "out", true);
        }

        private static void copy(string path, string name, long fileLength)
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            byte[] chunk = null;
            int bufferSize = 1024;


            Console.WriteLine("Copying " + path);

            FileStream fin;
            long index = 0;

            TryAgain1: try {
                fin = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                using (BinaryReader binReader = new BinaryReader(fin, new ASCIIEncoding())) {
                    while (data == null || (data.Length < fileLength)) {
                        binReader.BaseStream.Position = index;
                        chunk = binReader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
                        if (data == null) data = chunk; else data = CombineByteArrays(data, chunk);
                        index = binReader.BaseStream.Position;
                        Console.Write("\r{0} / {1}", data.Length, fileLength);

                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine("TA 1: " + ex.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(DELAY);
                goto TryAgain1;
            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(name, data);

            fin.Close();
            Console.Write(" ... OK");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        public static byte[] CombineByteArrays(byte[] first, byte[] second)
        {
            byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its the OS throwing the error not your app usually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the dialog looks like it is hard to guess exactly what is going on. My suggestion is to disable critical error dialogs:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern ErrorModes  SetErrorMode(ErrorModes uMode);

[Flags]
public enum ErrorModes : uint {
    SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS     = 0x0001,
    SEM_NOALIGNMENTFAULTEXCEPT = 0x0004,
    SEM_NOGPFAULTERRORBOX      = 0x0002,
    SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX     = 0x8000
}

...

var em = ErrorModes.SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS | ErrorModes.SEM_NOOPENFILEERRORBOX;
SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(em) | em);
```

(Calling it twice is [important](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040727-00/?p=38323))